# SQL get past months rows via microsecond timestamp?

Tags: mysql, sql, firebase, google-bigquery

I'm trying to get the past month of data from my table but all the timestamps are stored in microseconds. Currently I'm just counting all that I have to compare. How do I compare the microsecond timestamp stored in my table to todays microsecond timestamp?

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id) AS monthly_visitors
FROM `premium-apps.com_sidearm_fanapp_uiowa_IOS.app_events_20170104`
```

Comment: http://www.epochconverter.com/programming/mysql

Answer (score 4):

> How do I compare the microsecond timestamp stored in my table to todays microsecond timestamp?

In BigQuery Standard SQL you should use [TIMESTAMP_MICROS()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#timestamp_micros) function for this as well as [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#current_timestamp)

Comment: the answer usually as good as question is. sorry if you feel it didn't helped, but it answered exactly what you asked!